# Какое обращение следует использовать: Вы / вы / ты?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, термины, стиль

Первое, что бросилось в глаза при виде локализованного StackOverflow — это бессистемное* использование "Вы" с заглавной буквы. Споры вокруг местоимений не утихают до сих пор: одни говорят, что вежливо писать "Вы"; другие — что в Интернете обращаются не к конкретному человеку, а ко всем сразу, и правила предписывают в этом случае писать "вы" со строчной буквы; третьи кричат, что "Вы" — ископаемый анахронизм, и ему нет места в современном языке.

Но факт остаётся фактом: в Рунете "Вы" можно встретить разве что на пафосных страничках пафосных организаций, которые делают вид, что им есть дело до того, кто читает текст. Практически на всех сайтах же — "вы", в редких случаях — "ты".

Давайте же сделаем текст человеческим, а не будем уподобляться официозным бумажкам "Уважаемый клиент, Вы для нас очень дороги, поэтому мы подаем на Вас в суд".

<sub>* Где-то "Вы", где-то "вы" — переводчики не определились.</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Я придерживаюсь мнения, что, если рядом с местоимением нет имени, если страница общая для всех, а не написана специально для кого-то, то это никакое не личное обращение. То есть если письмо сгенерировано системой подписок, то оно уникальное, и на "Вы" я согласен. Когда я читаю справку, "вы" было бы более уместно, потому что правила едины для всех. В Туре сейчас, к слову, разброд и шатания.

Мнения, которые можно учесть при выборе:

- [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=rubric_88):

> **Таким образом, местоимения *Вы, Ваш* пишутся с прописной буквы при обращении к одному лицу в текстах следующих жанров:**
>
> а) личное письмо (адресат – одно лицо);
>
> б) официальные документы, адресованные одному лицу;
>
> в) анкеты, рекламные листовки (текст, адресованный неконкретному лицу).
>
> При обращении к нескольким лицам или неопределенному кругу лиц (например, при обращении к читательской аудитории газеты или журнала, при обращении к посетителям сайта, в объявлении, адресованном широкому кругу лиц, и т. п.) местоимения *вы, ваш* пишутся со строчной буквы: *Дорогие подписчики! Напоминаем вам, что...; На портале «Грамота.ру» опубликован новый интерактивный диктант. Проверьте вашу грамотность!*

- [Microsoft Style Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/3/af3d2fa6-f0ca-4398-9bca-3e6aec644e10/rus-rus-StyleGuide.pdf) (PDF):

> ## Pronouns
>
> **Capitalization of pronouns ''ваш'', ''вашего'', etc.**
>
> Pronouns ''ваш'', ''вашего'' are usually not capitalized. For example, they should not be capitalized in documentation, software or materials addressed to users in general. They are capitalized in private and business letters addressed to specific people.
>
> **Using forms ''ваш'', ''вашего'', etc.**
>
> In previous versions of Style Guide there were strict rules prohibiting the usage of personal pronouns "вы", "ваш", "вашего", "вам” etc. These rules are outdated, as Microsoft now strives to address users in a more personal, warm and friendly way. From now on the usage of prepositions should be more natural and close to informal, not scientific style. Nevertheless it does not mean that you should use personal pronouns whenever they are used in English, because in Russian they are generally less common
>
> When "you/your" is necessary to indicate the direction, to address the user in a personal way or to differentiate user’s account, data, rights etc from those of other people, you should use вы, ваш etc in your translation. Please also use these personal pronouns when the translation without them sounds clumsy or unnatural.

- [Артемий Лебедев](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/165/)

> ## § 165. Три правила про вы
>
> В русском языке существует местоимение вы, к которому прилагаются довольно простые правила употребления и неупотребления.
>
> ***Вы* всегда пишется с маленькой**
>
> Совершенно невыносима рекламно-подобострастная манера писать *Вы* с заглавной буквы. *Вы* — это множественное число, при обращении к одному человеку звучит уже достаточно почтительно (по сравнению с *ты*) и не требует дополнительных украшений.
>
> В качестве особого исключения можно писать *Вы* при личном обращении к невероятно уважаемому человеку (у каждого таких адресатов в жизни наберется человека три).
>
> В названии магазина «Все для Вас» и в рекламных словах «...потому что Вы можете себе это позволить» читается не уважение, а глупость. Не нужно бояться писать всегда и везде вы с маленькой буквы.

---

*Остальные варианты*.

**Вариант 1**

Как минимум в первой тысяче строк я старался поддерживать "Вы", где идет личное обращение. На мой взгляд, это проявление культуры и вежливости. Я использую "вы" только там, где обращение идет к группе лиц.

Над оригинальным переводом, скорее всего, трудилось несколько специалистов. Поэтому, да, "вы" можно встретить в нескольких вариантах.

Еще раз подчеркну, я за "Вы" для личного обращения, и за "вы" для обращения к группе пользователей. В принципе, можно ослабить это правило, оставив "Вы" исключительно для личных обращений по почте (подписок, например), и "вы" для всего остального.

"Ты" в переводе лучше вообще не употреблять.

Comment: На мой взгляд "Вы" на сайтах вообще не должно использоваться. Одно исключение из правил, это когда обращение идёт лично к пользователю и никому кроме него. К примеру, приходит письмо с сайта и оно адресовано лично пользователю, а не всем подряд. Типа: "Уважаемый, Иван Иванович! Наши холопы намедни собрали наиболее интересные вопросы, почтмейстер составил и послал Вам письмо, чтобы Вы могли быть в курсе". Использование "Вы" в обезличенных текстах это не просто дело вкуса, это неправильно.

Comment: @ixSci: чаще приходит "Уважаемый Иван Иванович! Вы себя плохо вели и поэтому мы Вас забанили на недельку".

Answer (score 2):

Это вопрос стиля. Как уже писал @Nicolas Chabanovsky: "Вы" используется при личном обращении, в остальных случаях "вы".

Собственно это правило и призвано разделять личные обращения от обращений к группе.

- Неверно считать это устаревшим и пафосным. Заглавная "В" не добавляет вежливости. Вежливость вообще невозможно добавить, если это не лицемерное пресмыкание. Сама форма обращения к личности на "Вы" является вежливой. Прошу отметить, что письменность является зеркалом устной речи, где нет границы между "В" и "в". И ещё раз подчёркиваю: единственное назначение заглавной "В" в местоимении "вы" - это указать, что обращение идёт к личности, а не группе людей
- Неверно считать ответ на комментарий конкретного человека, конкретному человеку, не личным обращением (если иное не явно). Не имеет значения, сколько человек это прочитает
- Неверно считать, что правила русского языка формируются набором их неправильного применения. Использование той или иной формы местоимения "вы" на так называемых "пафосных" сайтах, не изменяет правил русского языка. Как не меняет их и кругозор, человека делающего подобные выводы. В принципе кругозор отдельного человека достаточно ограничен. Для того и существуют правила, что б находить общий язык, а не говорить на  разных
- Неверно также и то, что автор поста в интернете обязательно
  обращается к группе (я с трудом представляю, как кто-то зачитывает
  текст с экрана группе слушателей)

Акцентирую внимание, что автор поста может обращаться и к одному человеку. Причём не обязательно конкретному. Классический пример:

> ... Вы, дорогой читатель, ...

Использовался Пушкиным и используется современниками. Хочу подчеркнуть, что автор обращается к конкретному человеку, заранее зная, что это обращение получат многие. Стоит учитывать и то, что читатели интернет-постов, не объединены в группу по сути, и получают эту информацию не единомоментно.

---

Подвергаю сомнению авторитет Артемия Лебедева в таких вопросах. Не существует групп и категорий людей к которым, и только к которым, применимо "Вы" при личном обращении. Дифференцирование людей на первый и второй сорта есть корень невежливости и безграмотности. В то же самое время, в своём посте он пишет про некорректность рекламных объявлений где использование "Вы" действительно странно. В ряде случаев (далеко не во всех) рекламное объявление "калька" с английского языка, где используются заглавные буквы во всех словах заголовка, что некорректно в русском языке. Хочу отметить ещё один из вариантов: "[...] мы Вас ждем [...] приходите всей семьёй". Здесь, следуя правилам русского языка, смысл таков, что остальных членов семьи никто не ждёт, но при этом их приглашают вместе с ожидаемым посетителем.

---

Предлагаю перефразировать вопрос (а не заниматься ложной трактовкой правил русского языка) какой стиль использовать на SO:

1. обращение к группе читателей, если иное не явно
2. обращение к читателю, если иное не явно

Конкретно для меня нет разницы. Но переводчик, должен понимать, что значит "вы" и "Вы" для того, что бы не вышло курьёзов. Предлагаю не тешить себя надеждами, что все пользователи интернета безграмотны в подобных вопросах, и к ним можно подходить с недостаточной тщательностью. По крайней мере, если чистота русского языка что то значит для SO на русском.

Я признателен переводчикам и причастным лицам, что вопросам грамотного написания уделяется внимание