# Несогласованное использование "Вы" и "вы" на сайте

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Вроде как недавно мне рассказывали, что [тут принято писать "вы"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/489/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%92%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%8B) с маленькой буковки. Однако, вот при отображении пустой [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) наблюдается сообщение с "Вы":

> Очередь кончилась! Если Вы ищете другие материалы для ...

> [image: вЫ]

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/553165) ещё наблюдается с большой буквы:

> [image: Вы]

Comment: Обращение к неопределённому лицу (с точки зрения автора - фиг знает, кто будет читать эти строки), значит со строчной "в" должно быть. Прописная - только если конкретное и известное лицо. Кстати, кажется, что аналогией для "вы" (когда с маленькой) является ключевое `static` из плюсов :)

Comment: @alexis031182 добавил ссылку на тему про "Вы/вы".

Comment: Перечитайте выбранный ответ к ссылке, которую Вы указали в вопросе, и процитируйте, если можно, место где "тут принято писать "вы" с маленькой буквы", а то у меня появились затруднения с поиском оного.

Comment: @edem не цитата, но [комментарий модератора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3201/%d0%a3%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c?lq=1#comment10216_3201).

Comment: «Вы» с большой употребляется при вежливом или официальном обращении к одному лицу, а «вы» с маленькой служит для обозначения множественности собеседников

Comment: Хм, в примере идёт обращение к конкретному лицу, тому, которое читает эти строки, значит-таки "Вы".

Comment: @Doofy это, можно сказать, устаревшая практика. на сегодняшний день только обращение к глубокоуважаемым личностям использует заглавную букву, причем в личной переписке. а в интернетах обращение к неизвестным индивидам допускает использование прописной буквы. такая вот загогулина)

Comment: @lexxl, прописная это и есть заглавная :)

Comment: Предлагаю заменить на «ты» :D

Comment: @andreymal в принципе это было бы лучшим вариантом, имхо обращение "вы" - остаток крепостничества, рабского прошлого. От этого требования "уважай меня, говори со мной на вы" и прочее.  В английском языке только you и только при добавлении титула/звания указывается уважение

Comment: @strangeqargo уж лучше "уважай меня, говори на вы", чем "не уважай, говори на ты". В повседневной жизни Вы наверное к незнакомому человеку на "ты" не будете обращаться, если хотите быть вежливым, конечно.

Comment: @alexolut я бы свернул значение "уважение/неуважение" до титулов и званий (заслуженных), а простое "ты" оставил для человеческого общения на равных.

Comment: @strangeqargo для общения на равных можно и "вы" использовать. К тому же буквы на клавиатуре рядом :)

Comment: @alexolut тогда всем придется на "вы", в принципе это лучше даже чем "ты"

Comment: Ох уж эти споры с "ты", "вы", "Вы"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Прошёлся по Transifex, поменял «Вы» на «вы», «Вас» на «вас», «Ваш» на «ваш» и т. п. в дофигалиарде мест. Надеюсь, ничего не пропустил.

Comment: А `Вами` меняли?

Comment: @alexolut: Вроде бы менял. Если нет, значит таки что-то пропустил :) // PS: пробежался по Transifex, форму «Вами» обнаружил только в начале предложений.

Comment: На [странице 404](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/jgkjgkjgkjgkjg) ещё осталось "Вами".

Comment: Не нашёл этого текста в Transifex. Судя по всему, страница 404 переведена «вручную».

Comment: @Roman: Отписался в чате Николасу. Он обещал поправить.

Comment: Поправили 404! Спасибо!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Отлично, ещё баг ушёл!