# Вас нужно уменьшить, или проблема перевода для Winter Bash

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, новогодние-шляпы

Во всплывающем окне Winter Bash (если вы ещё не успели полюбить шляпы) текст выглядит так:

> [image: Winter Bash]

Согласно [вопросу об использовании Вы/вы на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3318/176217), следует писать "вы" с маленькой буквы. Т.е. должно быть как минимум так:

> Stack Exchange приглашает вас отпраздновать конец замечательного года ШЛЯПАМИ!

К сожалению, данный текст недоступен для исправления с помощью transifex, а значит может быть поправлен только сотрудниками компании.

Заодно стоит принять во внимание, что "замечательного" слова больше не будет в этом тексте, как следует из [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357968/339911) на вопрос на MSE.

Comment: Хм.. Вроде на всех сайтах кроме SO их любят по умолчанию...